Get the size of a print layout element
My question is similar to this one that is unanswered :
QGIS Layout Print Composer: getting the height (etc.) variable of a certain layout item
In QGIS 3.36, is there a way to get the length of an element in a print layout (label item, scale bar, map item...) as a variable ?
In my case, I'm trying to center a label item, representing the scale as a text, relative to a scale bar.
The scale bar is fixed on the bottom right corner and expand to the left side if necessary. The segments width are fixed to 50 units.



I don't think this is possible, it appears there is still an open issue on the topic: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/25768
